# If $\overrightarrow{v}=(1, 0, 0)$, what can be deduced?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity

A question from my physics test (but actually it a question about vectors):

let $t\in [0, T]$ and let $\overrightarrow{v}(t)$ denote the velocity vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume that $\overrightarrow{v}(t)=(1, 0, 0)$ for any $t\in [0, T]$. What one can say about $\overrightarrow{v}$?

In my opinion the question is pretty vague. Anyway, I answered it means that the velocity is constant in any direction and has null components along $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ direction.
The lecturer said that my answer is not correct since I should have indicate in which halfplane/halfspace the velocity vector is placed, give information about magnitude (easy, its magnitude is $1$) and if there is a physical situation which guarantees that $\overrightarrow{v}=(1, 0, 0)$ is in that form.

I don't know how to answer these questions.

Could someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: I wish the question had asked what we can say about $\vec{r}$, namely $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_0+t\hat{x}$, but even that's worse wondering than "determine $\vec{r}$ as a function of $t$".

Comment: In general, _part_ of the reason you listen to lectures is to learn the actual material, and part is to learn the quirks of the lecturer so you can pass exams.  Just knowing the subject _in general_ doesn't help if the lecturer is riding a hobby-horse, or if they're trying to make a point that's actually important.  I'm not sure if the lecturer actually _did_ make special points about halfspaces and the other things they clearly emphasize, but if they did then -- for good grades -- you should have picked up on it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is an ambiguous question, and a poor question for an exam.

You can deduce that there is no acceleration. You can deduce the magnitude is one. You can deduce no Y or Z component, like you said.

For what it's worth, which "halfplane" is ambiguous. Does this mean XY half planes? Does it mean XZ halfplanes? What about halfspace, how are we dividing that?

The "physical situation" that guarantees it is in that form is, I guess, zero net force on an object. I don't know what else one can say.